# save the new document result from Word mailmerge in C#

Tags: c#, ms-word, mailmerge

I am performing a mail merge to new document using Word for Office 365

I am trying to save the new document to specified location.  However I don't know how to get a reference to this new document that is created after MailMerge.Execute.

I'm currently using ActiveDocument, but there is another document 'in the way' (I'm guessing it is the document with errors) that I have to close in addition to the original document that I close until ActiveDocument is something I want to save.

Is there a more robust way of getting a reference to the document created by MailMerge.Execute?

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string inDoc = @"C:\bob\doc.docx";
        string data = @"C:\bob\data.csv";
        string outDoc = @"C:\bob\out.docx";

        Application wordApp = new Application();
        Document wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(inDoc);

        wordDoc.MailMerge.OpenDataSource(data);

        wordDoc.MailMerge.Destination = WdMailMergeDestination.wdSendToNewDocument;
        wordDoc.MailMerge.SuppressBlankLines = true;
        wordDoc.MailMerge.Execute(false);

        // Close the input document
        wordDoc.Close(false);

        // Active document is now what?  The error document?
        // Close this too
        wordApp.ActiveDocument.Saved = true;
        wordApp.ActiveDocument.Close(false);

        // Now have reference to the new document
        wordApp.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2(outDoc, WdSaveFormat.wdFormatDocumentDefault);
        wordApp.ActiveDocument.Close(false);

        wordApp.Quit();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a more robust way of getting a reference to the document
>   created by MailMerge.Execute?

Unfortunately, no. It would have been useful if the `Execute` method would return that if execution is to a new document rather than the printer or email...

What I would do is create an array/list/collection/dictionary/whatever of all currently open documents before executing the mail merge. Then check whether `ActiveDocument` is in that "list". If not, you've got the right one. If it is, then loop the `wordApp.Documents` collection until you find one that is not in the "list".